# Ubuntu 14.04, disable password lock when waking from screensaver for ALL users

Tags: 14.04, command-line, password, lock-screen, screensaver

I am in the middle of setting up a bunch of lab computers running Ubuntu 14.04 at the local University and would like to disable the need to use a password when exiting screen saver (but not necessary disable the possibility to lock the screen) for all users.

If possible a command line solution that could be deployed over ssh would be preferred.

Comment: I recommend adding as many tags that uniquely apply as possible, for instance - you are looking for a [tag:command-line] solution involving [tag:lock-screen] and [tag:screensaver].  Additionally, this is a great way to see if your question already has a solution out there - you can search questions for multiple tags yourself - such as putting '[lock-screen][screensaver][password]' into the search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one way to achieve this taken from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/DisableScreenLock where the steps taken basically is:

1. Create a script lock_disable.sh containing

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
   ```
2. Make the file executable and add lock_disable.sh.desktop in  /etc/xdg/autostart/ with the following contents

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=/full/path/to/lock_disable.sh
   Hidden=false
   NoDisplay=false
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
   Name=LockScreen Disabled
   Comment=Disable the lock screen
   ```

   replacing /full/path/to/ with the correct path to where lock_disable.sh is kept.

What this will do is change the setting for each user when they login to the system such that the lock-screen does not become enabled.